# Class loader issue. Child class from the same jar is 'not a subtype'

Tags: java, classloader

How could it be that `EnvironmentPropertySource` being loaded from the same log4j-api-2.10.0.jar is not a subtype of `PropertySource`?

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.10.1-1.cdh5.10.1.p0.10/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
[Loaded org.slf4j.spi.LoggerFactoryBinder from file:/app/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.10.1-1.cdh5.10.1.p0.10/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar]
[Loaded org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerAdapter from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar]
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil$ThreadContextClassLoaderGetter from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertySource from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.BiConsumer from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesPropertySource from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertyFilePropertySource from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertySource$Comparator from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertySource from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.logging.log4j.util.EnvironmentPropertySource from file:/home/extproc/WMA/bmss/bmss-dev/producer/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar]
[Loaded java.util.ServiceConfigurationError from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-oracle-1.8.0.151.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
Exception in thread "main" [Loaded java.lang.Throwable$PrintStreamOrWriter from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-oracle-1.8.0.151.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-oracle-1.8.0.151.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeySet from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-oracle-1.8.0.151.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertySource: Provider org.apache.logging.log4j.util.EnvironmentPropertySource not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:319)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil$Environment.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:310)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:69)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.<clinit>(PropertiesUtil.java:49)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.isIgnoreTccl(LoaderUtil.java:256)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.loadClass(LoaderUtil.java:159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.<clinit>(StackLocator.java:65)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil.<clinit>(StackLocatorUtil.java:28)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    at com.company.producer.BmssProducerApp.<clinit>(BmssProducerApp.java:42)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:695)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: You're using multiple versions: `slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar` `log4j-api-2.10.0.jar`. I'm not surprised it doesn't work

Comment: All classes were loaded from log4j-api-2.10.0.jar, should I not believe java classloader logs?

Comment: No they weren't: `LoggerFactoryBinder` is from `slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar`, the rest are from `2.10.0`

Comment: I cannot remove 1.7.5 it is part of the claster and system classpath. But I can add 1.7.5 to application classpath and it will be loaded by same classloader which fixed the issue. Thanks a lot for your notice!

Answer (score 1):

On the first hand, Check whether you have multiple versions of the same jar.

Secondly, if you are using an IDE, clear cache and **clean and build** your project again.

Comment: well said...typical case is to have a WAR inside an EAR. The jar is present in two copies, one in the ear (or ear/lib) and the other in the war.